Problem receiving files from multiple uploads with jquery
I'm trying to send multiple images to the server using ajax and php.
HTML:
<div class="upload-container" id="uploadContainer">
    <div class="upload-box show">
        <span class="plus-sign">+</span>
        <input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple>
        <button class="delete-icon" type="button">×</button>
    </div>
</div>

JAVASCRIPT:
This styles the file field by creating a square box that when clicked opens the image selector and incorporates up to five files. Worked properly
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const uploadContainer = document.getElementById('uploadContainer');
const imageUploadForm = document.getElementById('form-review');
let imageCount = 0;
const maxImages = 5;

function createUploadBox() {
    if (imageCount >= maxImages) return;

    const uploadBox = document.createElement('div');
    uploadBox.classList.add('upload-box');
    uploadBox.innerHTML = `
        <span class="plus-sign">+</span>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="images[]" multiple>
        <button class="delete-icon" type="button">×</button>
    `;
    uploadContainer.appendChild(uploadBox);

    setTimeout(() => uploadBox.classList.add('show'), 10);

    attachUploadEvents(uploadBox);
}

function attachUploadEvents(uploadBox) {
    const input = uploadBox.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    const deleteIcon = uploadBox.querySelector('.delete-icon');
    
    uploadBox.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (uploadBox.classList.contains('filled')) return;
        input.click();
    });

    input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
        const validFiles = files.slice(0, maxImages - imageCount);
        validFiles.forEach(file => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                const imgBox = document.createElement('div');
                imgBox.classList.add('upload-box', 'show', 'filled');
                imgBox.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${e.target.result}" alt="Image">
                    <button class="delete-icon" type="button">×</button>
                `;
                uploadContainer.insertBefore(imgBox, uploadContainer.lastElementChild);
                attachDeleteEvent(imgBox);
                imageCount++;
                if (imageCount >= maxImages) {
                    const emptyUploadBox = document.querySelector('.upload-box:not(.filled)');
                    if (emptyUploadBox) emptyUploadBox.remove();
                }
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

        input.value = '';
    });

    deleteIcon.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        uploadBox.classList.remove('show');
        setTimeout(() => {
            uploadBox.remove();
            imageCount--;
            ensureOneEmptyUploadBox();
        }, 300);
    });
}

window.resetUploadBoxes = function() {
    const filledUploadBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.upload-box.filled');
    filledUploadBoxes.forEach(box => box.remove());
    imageCount = 0;
    ensureOneEmptyUploadBox();
}

function attachDeleteEvent(uploadBox) {
        const deleteIcon = uploadBox.querySelector('.delete-icon');
        deleteIcon.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            uploadBox.classList.remove('show');
            setTimeout(() => {
                uploadBox.remove();
                imageCount--;
                ensureOneEmptyUploadBox();
        }, 300);
    });
 }

function ensureOneEmptyUploadBox() {
    const emptyUploadBox = document.querySelector('.upload-box:not(.filled)');
    if (!emptyUploadBox && imageCount < maxImages) {
        createUploadBox();
    }
}

attachUploadEvents(document.querySelector('.upload-box'));

$('#button-review').on('click', function() {
   var formData = new FormData($('#form-review')[0]);

    // Loop through all file input elements
    $('input[type="file"]', $('#form-review')).each(function(index, input) {
        if (input.files.length > 0) {
            formData.append('image[]', input.files[0]);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/write&product_id={{ product_id }}',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-review').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-review').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert-dismissible').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                $('#review').after('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + '</div>');
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#review").offset().top}, 800);
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                resetUploadBoxes();
                $('#review').after('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '</div>');
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#review").offset().top}, 800);

                $('input[name=\'name\']').val('');
                $('textarea[name=\'text\']').val('');
                $('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').prop('checked', false);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
});

PHP:
$files = [];
if (!empty($this->request->files) && is_array($this->request->files)) {
   foreach ($this->request->files as $key) {
      if ($key['name'] != "") {
        $files[] = array(
            'name' => $key['name'],
            'type' => $key['type'],
            'tmp_name' => $key['tmp_name'],
            'error' => $key['error'],
            'size' => $key['size']
        );
      }
    }
}

This works almost fine, but I can't receive the images server-side. The array that arrives is empty. I can send the form texts and no errors occur. I analyzed the code, including with AI help, and found nothing wrong.

input.files[0] only sends the first file. You need to append all of input.files, not just [0].

change to formData.append('images[]', file); didn't solve

Please clarify how your frontend part actually works. You say, "This styles the file field by creating a square box that when clicked opens the image selector and incorporates up to five files." - but to me it looks like you are creating up to five separate input fields, which each allow the selection of multiple files? And your function attachUploadEvents appears to not do what its name pretends it would, but only provides a client-side preview of the selected images; the actual upload happens via the click handler assigned to #button-review instead ...

var formData = new FormData($('#form-review')[0]); - isn't #form-review the form that contains all those input fields? If so, then this should prepare the whole form including all fields that are valid for submission already, so you should not even need to add the files to this individually afterwards. You neglected to show us the actual form, but does that have the proper enctype necessary for file uploads? I think that might be a requirement for the FormData constructor to encode everything properly into multipart format.

@CBroe I don't think that's required. FormData always encodes as multipart/form-data. The attribute is only needed if the form is being submitted normally, rather than with AJAX.

You need to loop through all the files in each file input, not just append the first file from each. So replace
// Loop through all file input elements
$('input[type="file"]', $('#form-review')).each(function(index, input) {
    if (input.files.length > 0) {
        formData.append('image[]', input.files[0]);
    }
});

with
// Loop through all file input elements
$('input[type="file"]', $('#form-review')).each((index, input) => 
  [...input.files].forEach(file => formData.append('image[]', file)
);

Although as CBroe commented, var formData = new FormData($('#form-review')[0]) should already have put the files into formData and this loop is unnecessary.
